# Grails: getting return from the mailService that mail send or not

Tags: java, grails

This is the code i recently used

```
if(!toAddress.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            mailService.sendMail {
                to toAddress
                subject "This is a test mail"
                body "Hello, This is a test mail."
            }
}
```

but i dont know how to get the return result from the sendMail

Comment: Is the mail being sent? Is this the last statement in the method?

Comment: yes, here after there is no execution regarding the email

Answer (score 0):

I see in plugin [tests](https://github.com/gpc/grails-mail/blob/master/test/integration/grails/plugin/mail/MailServiceTests.groovy) that method throws GrailsMailException if something fails.
So you can use try-catch:

```
try {
   mailService.sendMail {
       to toAddress
       subject "This is a test mail"
       body "Hello, This is a test mail."
    }
} catch(GrailsMailException e) {
    log.warn('Message failed with exception', e) 
}
```

Comment: ok, but when using the `async` parameter and set  to `true`  then the mail will send as an thread and exception cant be caught in the above `catch` block. Any resolution for that?

Comment: I see in plugin source if async specified then message is sent in a separate thread. So i think there is no way to check result for async send. I suggest you take a look at https://github.com/kefirfromperm/grails-asynchronous-mail. This plugin stores messages in the database, so you can check message state.